# Prelaunch security checklist for site built in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, security

Before launching a site built in Codeigniter, what kind of security issues should one check for? What my site features is login, form handling, restricting pages, etc. It is a booking system for student cabins. Feel free to write about general security issues.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, no web site is 100% secure and maximum security is typically not the goal. It is a tradeoff between security and usability. If you are not actually taking orders on your site and dealing with deposits or payments, your needs are somewhat less. Here's a start:

1. Basic premise is to deny everything to do with the booking portion until proper authorization and authentication is done and then allow access to that portion of your site. Not sure how your site is designed to accomplish this.
2. Remove all code that printed detailed error information or showed session or variable data used during the development.
3. Verify all form input goes through validation.
4. Re-check what mySQL permissions you give your users versus visitors versus the admin. User should just have SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE. Visitor just SELECT.
5. Verify passwords are not stored as plaintext.
6. Do you allow uploaded files? If so, need to prevent Remote File Inclusion attacks.
7. Did you enable CSRF in Codeigniter to prevent a CSRF attack?

That's a start. I am sure others can add their experience.